# Django routing - The empty path didn't match any of these

Tags: django, routes

Very basic question and I was surprised I wasn't able to find an answer. I'm just starting looking at django and did an out-of-box intallation. Created a project and created an app.
The default content of urls.py is very simple:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

And if I open the django site home page, I get the content with a rocket picture. However, like I said, I have created another app in the project, let's say called '**bboard**'. And I have created a simple 'hello world' function in **bboard/views.py**

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse('Hello world')
```

to enable it for access through browser, I have modified the original **urls.py** file in the following way:

```
from bboard.views import index
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('bboard/', index),
]
```

This way I can access **localhost:port/admin** and **localhost:port/bboard** URLs, but if I try to open the home page with **localhost:port** now, I get **Page not found** error.

**Using the URLconf defined in samplesite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    admin/
    bboard/
The empty path didn't match any of these.**

if I comment out the second item in urlpatterns list, everything works. So why does the additional pattern impact this and what needs to be done to fix it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before you add your own routes Django will serve the default home page at the '/' url. After you add your own route config, django no longer serves up its default sample home page.

From the django's `django/views/debug.py`:

```
def technical_404_response(request, exception):
    """Create a technical 404 error response. `exception` is the Http404."""
    try:
        error_url = exception.args[0]['path']
    except (IndexError, TypeError, KeyError):
        error_url = request.path_info[1:]  # Trim leading slash

    try:
        tried = exception.args[0]['tried']
    except (IndexError, TypeError, KeyError):
        tried = []
    else:
        if (not tried or (                  # empty URLconf
            request.path == '/' and
            len(tried) == 1 and             # default URLconf
            len(tried[0]) == 1 and
            getattr(tried[0][0], 'app_name', '') == getattr(tried[0][0], 'namespace', '') == 'admin'
        )):
            return default_urlconf(request)
```

Note the final `else` block that returns a `default_urlconf` if the only url path included is the admin path and the requested url is `/`. This `default_urlconf` is the sample Rocket page you mentioned. As soon as you add any of your own routes the `if` statement in the `else` block will be false so the `default_urlconf` is not returned and instead falls through to the normal 404 handler.

Here's the `default_urlconf`

```
def default_urlconf(request):
    """Create an empty URLconf 404 error response."""
    with Path(CURRENT_DIR, 'templates', 'default_urlconf.html').open() as fh:
        t = DEBUG_ENGINE.from_string(fh.read())
    c = Context({
        'version': get_docs_version(),
    })

    return HttpResponse(t.render(c), content_type='text/html')
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed explaniation! But not sure I fully get it... You say, if I do not add an additional route, the django welcome page I see is actually a default 404 page. But in this case I would expect seeing it also accessing some non-existing route, like localhost/smth but in this case I see a real 404 page, not the one with the rocket...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'll edit to clarify. I you look at the code snippet above it only returns the `default_urlconf` if `request.path` is `/`. That `default_urlconf` renders the rocket page. Otherwise the `technical_404_response` function continues past the snippet I pasted and returns the default `404` page.

Answer (score 10):

You need to add an empty url in root `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('bboard.urls'))
]
```

Comment: in this case I'm getiing TypeError: view must be a callable or a list/tuple in the case of include().

Answer (score 0):

The other reason that you might be getting this error is because

1. You haven't passed an empty URL inside your application URL
2. Kindly (this is a simple but a very crucial one) check for typos