# Page not found (404), The empty path didn’t match any of these

Tags: django

I know this question is asked in many different forms, but I can't find a solution for my problem;

My problem is I need to display the static pages and I have run into this error: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIfAg.png)

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in djangoAPIReact.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
^ ^department$ [name='department']
^ ^department/([0-9]+)$ [name='departmentApi']
^ ^employee$ [name='employee']
^ ^employee/([0-9]+)$ [name='employeeApi']
^ ^Employee/SaveFile$ [name='SaveFile']
^ ^media/(?P<path>.*)$
The empty path didn’t match any of these.
```

I have also used URL instead of re_path but it doesn't work, I am newly to Django please any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
`urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    re_path(r'^', include('EmployeeApp.urls'))
]`
```

App.urls:

```
`urlpatterns=[
    re_path(r'^department$',views.departmentApi, name='department'),
    re_path(r'^department/([0-9]+)$',views.departmentApi, name='departmentApi'),

    re_path(r'^employee$',views.employeeApi, name='employee'),
    re_path(r'^employee/([0-9]+)$',views.employeeApi, name='employeeApi'),

    re_path(r'^Employee/SaveFile$', views.SaveFile, name='SaveFile')
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)`
```

The view:

```
@csrf_exempt
def departmentApi(request, id=0):
  if request.method == 'GET':
    department = Departments.objects.all()
    departments_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(department, many=True)
    return JsonResponse(departments_serializer.data, safe=False)

  elif request.method == 'POST':
    department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    department_serializer = DepartmentSerializer(data=department_data)
    if department_serializer.is_valid():
      department_serializer.save()
      return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!", safe=False)
    return JsonResponse("Failed ro Add.",safe=False)

  elif request.method=='PUT':
    department_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
    department=Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=department_data['DepartmentId'])
    department_serializer=DepartmentSerializer(department,data=department_data)
    if department_serializer.is_valid():
        department_serializer.save()
        return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully!!", safe=False)
    return JsonResponse("Failed to Update.", safe=False)

  elif request.method == 'DELETE':
    department = Departments.objects.get(DepartmentId=id)
    department.delete()
    return JsonResponse("Deleted Successfully!!", safe=False)

@csrf_exempt
def employeeApi(request,id=0):
    if request.method=='GET':
        employees = Employees.objects.all()
        employees_serializer = EmployeeSerializer(employees, many=True)
        return JsonResponse(employees_serializer.data, safe=False)

    elif request.method=='POST':
        employee_data=JSONParser().parse(request)
        employee_serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=employee_data)
        if employee_serializer.is_valid():
            employee_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Added Successfully!!" , safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Add.",safe=False)
    
    elif request.method=='PUT':
        employee_data = JSONParser().parse(request)
        employee=Employees.objects.get(EmployeeId=employee_data['EmployeeId'])
        employee_serializer=EmployeeSerializer(employee,data=employee_data)
        if employee_serializer.is_valid():
            employee_serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse("Updated Successfully!!", safe=False)
        return JsonResponse("Failed to Update.", safe=False)

    elif request.method=='DELETE':
        employee=Employees.objects.get(EmployeeId=id)
        employee.delete()
        return JsonResponse("Deleted Succeffully!!", safe=False)


@csrf_exempt
def SaveFile(request):
  file=request.FILES['myFile']
  file_name = default_storage.save(file.name,file)
  
  return JsonResponse(file_name,safe=False)
```

Comment: Well you don't have an empty url pattern, as to it matching the last one, is `settings.MEDIA_URL` set to an _empty string_?

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem, I have initialized in the settings.py as so
 `MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
  MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")`

Comment: I have found the answer here: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57596664/django-routing-the-empty-path-didnt-match-any-of-these`